# For rings, are additive identity elements (often depicted 0), equivalent to multiplicative absorption elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an ambiguity in abstract algebra texts I keep coming across. A perfect example is in defining the "zero divisor".  [image]

How am I supposed to take the "0"?  Because authors choose to use the familiar symbols from the real numbers, it conflates the concepts unnecessarily.

I dont know if "0" refers to additive identities, or if its referring to multiplicative absorption elements.  Are these seemingly disparate notions intimately related in the most abstract sense?

To be clear, since we are dealing with multi-operator structures (fields and rings), there are two different operators I can interpret the 0 through.  I was never taught that an additive identity was the same as a multiplicative absorption element; I just know they happen to be the same thing in the real numbers but I dont know this to be a general truth for rings.

Comment: $0$ denotes the additive identity.  It is true that it is also a multiplicative absorbing element...that follows from the usual ring axioms.   There can't be any other multiplicative absorbing element in a ring since $0\times r=0$ for any $r\in R$.

Comment: following @lulu comment which I agree... the $0$ is just a symbol which is choosen because of familiarity with real numbers such as the operation is $+$. You can use other symbols such as $\Delta$ instead of $+$ and use $\pi$ instead of $0$.. however it usually does not happen because of such strutures as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ are famous rings and easy to get some inspiration to study this subject

Comment: Well, 0 frequently does denote the additive identity but doesnt have to. And it shouldnt be used at all.  What guarantee do I have that absoprtion element isnt the meaning I should be using in context, considering multiplication is the specific operator being used.

Comment: Have you referred to the definition of the concept of a ring in the algebra texts that you are accusing of being ambiguous. I think you will find that they will clearly define what $0$ means when we discuss a given ring, with no reference to the real numbers or any notion of "multiplicative absorption element". Edit: after your last comment, you need to tell us exactly what book or books you are complaining about.

Comment: My text defines a ring as such: Let $(R,*)$ be an abelian group, $(R,#)$ is a semigroup, if $#$ is distributive over $*$ then $(R,*,#)$ is a ring.  The text did it this way so as to not repeat previous definitions and to use the terminology already established.

Comment: Any standard reference should list the defining properties of rings.  $0$ should be defined there.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) for instance.  There really isn't anything controversial here.

Comment: Is that the same text from which your examples are taken?  What notation does your text adopt for the two identity elements?

Comment: My text typically uses e for the additive identity and i for the multiplicative identity and z for absorption elements.  But not in the aforementioned case where the subject matter was loosely connected to the reals but no clarity given on how 0 was being used.

Comment: Well, that is highly unusual.  But it's just notation, your text can use whatever letters it likes for these things. If your text then proceeded to switch to $0$ for the additive identity but never said it was switching notations, then that is poor writing.

Comment: Well, regardless of any criticisms to my texts author, can someone answer the fundamental abstract concept I eluded to in my OP?  In defining zero-divisors, by using multiplication, it is implied that we are talking about absorption.  Is the 0 in this case the additive identity?  Does anyone know abstract algebra well enough to elevate themselves out of the real numbers and speak most generally?

Comment: Any reference to $0$ in the context of ring theory is speaking of the additive identity.  Any writer who sought to use it in a different way would need to spell that out explicitly and even then, it would be terrible notation (I for one would regard it as an attempt to be deliberately confusing).

Comment: Please tell us what text you are using, so that we can subject it to reasonable critical analysis.

Comment: Please do not use images in lieu of text. They are not searchable, making it harder for future users to realize your post may be relevant. They are not accessible (unless you provide explicit description of the content where it says "enter image description here", which you did not do; and if you do, you might as well just type it up to begin with) so users who rely on screen readers are left unable to know your post contents. And they do not adapt to different displays, which may make them illegible or too large for users. This is very little text, you can just type it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the additive identity in a general ring is always a multiplicative absorbing element.

Consider an arbitrary ring $R$, with additive identity $0$. For any $a\in R$, we can see that $$a\cdot 0 = a \cdot (0 + 0) = a\cdot 0 + a \cdot 0$$

Thus we have shown that $a\cdot 0 = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$. We know by closure that $a\cdot 0 = b$ for some $b\in R$, so we can add the additive inverse of $b$ to both sides of our equation. We denote the additive inverse of $b$ in the usual fashion by $-b$. Thus we conclude that $a\cdot 0 - b = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 - b$, so indeed $0 = a\cdot 0$, thus $0$ is an absorbing element as required.